# Visual Studio: Vector of Unique Pointers of Subclasses Crashes

Tags: visual-studio, c++11

In Visual Studio 2015, the code shown below crashes at the exit of foo(), with this error message: HEAP[NameOfExecutable.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00520000, 005332D4 )

Notes:

- When I remove the "virtual" keyword from B::bob(), the program works perfectly fine.
- The program runs correctly from a command-line (outside of Visual Studio), when compiled with "g++ -std=c++11".
- Using std::move() within push_back() didn't change the output.

`#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  int a;
};

class B : public A
{
  int b;
  virtual void bob() { };
};

void foo()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> test;
  test.push_back(std::unique_ptr<B>(new B));
}

int main()
{
  foo();
  std::cout << "Reached the end\n";
  std::cin.get();
}`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug the code, you'll notice that the exception arises at the exit point of `foo()` - when the destructor for `test` is called.

Both `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` manage their memory of course, so somewhere at this point `B` object that you just allocated will be destroyed.

The problem here is that you store it by an `A` pointer, so the `A` class destructor will be called.

To fix that, just introduce public virtual destructor to 'A':

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, making this destructor virtual allows B's default destructor to be called, correct?

Comment: @AaronK sure, it's just like with regular `virtual` methods - if it's `virtual` in a base class, then it's automatically `virtual` in the descendants; of course you can always explicitly specify B's destructor as `virtual` too, just to clarify the code

Comment: I should probably also add that the whole problem is not about `A` destructor missing something, both `A` and `B` destructors can have empty bodies, it's just that `delete` on a base pointer with no `virtual` destructor is UB.

Comment: Ahhhh, so the UB-ness is why it was working with g++ but not with Visual Studio's compiler. That makes sense.